# VPN or Zero Trust? Could you please assess my needs,

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [VPN or Zero Trust?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/79268/vpn-or-zero-trust)

Answer (score 1):

Your question was closed for being off topic - it's about host-based security and opinion-oriented. Why do you think that is wrong?

You can challenge the closure here at Meta but you can't just repeat the question.